# NuGet package includes file with special characters

Tags: nuget, special-characters

I am currently in the process of creating a NuGet package from an ASP.NET MVC (called "Library" from now on) project to use as a base for some more advanced ASP.NET MVC projects.

My "Library" project uses the `bootstrap.chosen` NuGet package and this includes a file called `chosen-sprite.png` and a file called `chosen-sprite@2x.png`.

While the first file (without the `@`) is not included in the NuGet package (as is expected), the second file is.

When increasing the verbosity of the NuGet exe call the log shows the following messages:

```
Add file 'C:\Development\PersonRegister\Rubicon.RegisterNova.UI\Content\chosen-sprite@2x.png' to package as 'content\Content\chosen-sprite%402x.png'
File from dependency is not changed. File 'Content\chosen-sprite.png' is not added.
```

I already checked if the `chosen-sprite@2x.png` was modified (by using BeyondCompare) and even tried copying the original file from the NuGet package in its place, but for some reason `nuget pack`still seems to think that it is necessary to include the file in my NuGet package.

My theory is, that NuGet does not handle the `@` sign correctly and that is the cause of the error (especially since the bootstrap file without `@` works without a problem). Further evidence that NuGet probably does not handly "special" characters correctly lies in the fact that when installing my NuGet package in a project, the file added is actually named `chosen-sprite%402x.png` instead of `chosen-sprite@2x.png`.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? Is there a way to workaround the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a known bug in NuGet, see:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1117 (closed as duplicate, original problem: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1087).